# Extract integers from string value in a pandas data frame cell

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, ipython

I have a data frame train_df and it has a column named AgeuponOutcome which contains values as follows
AgeuponOutcome

```
1 year
1 year
2 years
3 weeks
2 years
1 month
3 weeks
3 weeks
5 months
1 year
2 years
2 years
4 years
```

Given below is my full data set.

```
OutcomeType AnimalType  SexuponOutcome  AgeuponOutcome  Breed   Color
Return_to_owner Dog Neutered Male   1 year  Shetland Sheepdog Mix   Brown/White
Euthanasia  Cat Spayed Female   1 year  Domestic Shorthair Mix  Cream Tabby
Adoption    Dog Neutered Male   2 years Pit Bull Mix    Blue/White
Transfer    Cat Intact Male 3 weeks Domestic Shorthair Mix  Blue Cream
Transfer    Dog Neutered Male   2 years Lhasa Apso/Miniature Poodle Tan
Transfer    Dog Intact Female   1 month Cairn Terrier/Chihuahua Shorthair   Black/Tan
Transfer    Cat Intact Male 3 weeks Domestic Shorthair Mix  Blue Tabby
Transfer    Cat Unknown 3 weeks Domestic Shorthair Mix  Brown Tabby
Adoption    Dog Spayed Female   5 months    American Pit Bull Terrier Mix   Red/White
Adoption    Dog Spayed Female   1 year  Cairn Terrier   White
Transfer    Cat Unknown 2 years Domestic Shorthair Mix  Black
Adoption    Dog Spayed Female   2 years Miniature Schnauzer Mix Silver
Adoption    Dog Neutered Male   4 years Pit Bull Mix    Brown
```

Given below is the code I have used to extract the integers from the string values in AgeuponOutcome column.

```
word='month'  
l = len(train_df)
    for i in range(l):
        if word in train_df.loc[i, 'AgeuponOutcome']: 
            print re.findall("\d+", train_df.loc[i, 'AgeuponOutcome'])
```

### But it gives the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-8a6df57d3cb9> in <module>()
      1 l = len(train_df)
      2 for i in range(l):
----> 3     if word in train_df.loc[i, 'AgeuponOutcome']:
      4         print re.findall("\d+", train_df.loc[i, 'AgeuponOutcome'])

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Can you tell me how to fix the error and extract the value. 
For example, I need to extract 1 from '1 year' and print 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = (df.AgeuponOutcome.str.extract('(\d+) (\w+)', expand=True))
df1.columns = ['a','b']
print (df1)
    a       b
0   1    year
1   1    year
2   2   years
3   3   weeks
4   2   years
5   1   month
6   3   weeks
7   3   weeks
8   5  months
9   1    year
10  2   years
11  2   years
12  4   years

print (df1.loc[df1.b.str.contains('month'), 'a'])
5    1
8    5
Name: a, dtype: object

print (df1.loc[df1.b.str.contains('year'), 'a'])
0     1
1     1
2     2
4     2
9     1
10    2
11    2
12    4
Name: a, dtype: object
```

If you need output as new columns:

```
df1['month'] = (df1.loc[df1.b.str.contains('month'), 'a'])
df1['year'] = (df1.loc[df1.b.str.contains('year'), 'a'])
df1['week'] = (df1.loc[df1.b.str.contains('week'), 'a'])
print (df1)
    a       b month year week
0   1    year   NaN    1  NaN
1   1    year   NaN    1  NaN
2   2   years   NaN    2  NaN
3   3   weeks   NaN  NaN    3
4   2   years   NaN    2  NaN
5   1   month     1  NaN  NaN
6   3   weeks   NaN  NaN    3
7   3   weeks   NaN  NaN    3
8   5  months     5  NaN  NaN
9   1    year   NaN    1  NaN
10  2   years   NaN    2  NaN
11  2   years   NaN    2  NaN
12  4   years   NaN    4  NaN
```

EDIT by comment:

You can use:

```
#convert to int
df1['a'] = df1.a.astype(int)

#divide by constant to column a
df1.loc[df1.b.str.contains('month'), 'a'] = df1.loc[df1.b.str.contains('month'), 'a'] / 12
df1.loc[df1.b.str.contains('week'), 'a'] = df1.loc[df1.b.str.contains('week'), 'a']  /52.1429
print (df1)
           a       b
0   1.000000    year
1   1.000000    year
2   2.000000   years
3   0.057534   weeks
4   2.000000   years
5   0.083333   month
6   0.057534   weeks
7   0.057534   weeks
8   0.416667  months
9   1.000000    year
10  2.000000   years
11  2.000000   years
12  4.000000   years
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response and can you help me to filter the strings with the word 'month' also?

Comment: I dont understand, because my solution parse `month` and `year`. Can you explain it better?

Comment: I want to create a separate column to my data frame containing the age in years, (In this case, I need to filter the data in months and convert to years.)  can you help me with that? (To get data as integers and create a seperate column while converting data in months to years)

Comment: I need to create a one column instead of three columns, which contains age in years

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Give me a time.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much

Comment: It is exactly the answer. Thanks a lot for the help